# Conditional type aliasing

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to be able to present a choice to the user - whether to use 16bit indices (in OpenGL) or 32bit indices. In C++, I'd probably just create an alias for int or short, but I don't seem to have the option in C#. Basically what I'm going for can be summed up in the class below:

```
using System;

namespace Something
{
    public class Conditional
    {
        public Conditional(Boolean is16Bit)
        {
            if (is16Bit)
            {
                SOMETYPE is Int16
            }
            else
            {
                SOMETYPE is Int32
            }
        }

        private List<SOMETYPE> _something;
    }
}
```

The aliasing (if it can be done) would be vastly better - I just don't want to force anyone using this code into writing #define statements, is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: `if (is16Bit){ Console.WriteLine("16bit");} else { Console.WriteLine("32bit");}` ?

Comment: I wrote that I need to use it as indices in OpenGL.. I'll update the question

Comment: I think it is unwise to wrap something that needs maximum performance (like openGL) with classes. Remember that objects are always heap allocated but ints and longs only when boxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an interface and a factory, something like this:

```
public interface IConditional
{
    void AddIndex(int i);
}

private class Conditional16 : IConditional
{
    List<Int16> _list = new List<Int16>();

    public void AddIndex(int i)
    {
        _list.Add((short)i);
    }
}

private class Conditional32 : IConditional
{
    List<Int32> _list = new List<Int32>();

    public void AddIndex(int i)
    {
        _list.Add(i);
    }
}

public static class ConditionalFactory
{
    public static IConditional Create(bool is16Bit)
    {
        if (is16Bit)
        {
            return new Conditional16();
        }
        else
        {
            return new Conditional32();
        }
    }
}
```

Your code (and callers of it) can do everything against `IConditional` without caring which of the concrete representations it is.

Comment: My class is too long for this approach. But it seems more correct anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you could use a generic for this:

```
namespace Something
{
    public class Conditional<T>
    {
        private List<T> _something = new List<T>();
        private Conditional()
        {
            // prevents instantiation except through Create method
        }

        public Conditional<T> Create()
        {
            // here check if T is int or short
            // if it's not, then throw an exception

            return new Conditional<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

And to create one:

```
if (is16Bit)
    return Conditional<short>.Create();
else
    return Conditional<int>.Create();
```

Comment: And is there a way to limit it only to Int16 and Int32?

Comment: Only at runtime by checking the type of T and throwing exceptions if it does not fit.

Comment: @JimMischel How would you use the instantiation code? I mean if you use it direct in code there should be two branches - one for short and one for int. If you want to create an extra method that returns an object of type Conditional<T> - what would this methods return value look like?

Comment: I up-voted both answers but accepted the other one. This, even though it would save me writing more code, seems like a hack - or am I wrong?

Comment: @PavelMatuska: The interface is a fine idea and should work well.

Comment: @pasty: I can't answer your question without more context. Most likely you'd want separate branches, one to work with `int` and one to work with `short`, with some type coercion code in the middle. There are several ways to do it, depending on context.

Comment: @JimMischel While trying to answer the question i came also to the exact solution like you - a generic class. I wanted also to make use of *var* and to return either *List<short>* or *List<int>* and so avoid branches, but this part didn't work as expected for me. I saw your **return ...** code and i thought you have a solution for the dynamic return value. :)